# How can I add autocomplete to Vim for non-standard Python libraries?

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete

For example, I have a Python script using the Google App Engine SDK:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
```

The module `db` has a submodule `Key`, so I try to use autocomplete on it:

`db.K`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

But at the bottom of the Vim window, I get the following:

```
-- Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found
```

How do I include the path to non-standard Python libraries so that Vim autocompletion can find them? And also display their docstrings?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add your library files to your tags file. For instance, if you have installed the Google App Engine via pip in a virtual environment located in env/:

```
virtualenv --no-site-package env/
source env/bin/activate
pip install google_appengine
```

... then you should execute:

```
ctags -R --python-kinds=-i -o tags env/
```

If you did not install google_appengine through pip, then you should locate the path to your python libraries (hint: it should be indicated by $PYTHONPATH. And according to [this](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) reference page: "on Unix, this is usually .:/usr/local/lib/python.") and replace env/ by the path you found.

Finally, your .vimrc file should parse your tags file. For instance, in my .vimrc, I have:

```
set tags+=/path/to/my/tags
```

Comment: How about if I did not use `pip`? Say, just do something like point to the path of the library? What's the procedure for that?

Answer (score 1):

I grabbed this from natw's vimrc (I think...maybe sontek), but it should do the trick, so long as your packages are findable by your current install of Python. This lets you use gf, but also sets up searching these files for autocompletion.  Note the `py <<EOF` part, which starts a section interpreted in Python. This means you'd have to have the python interpreter installed in vim to use it.

```
function! LoadPythonPath() 
py <<EOF
    # load PYTHONPATH into vim, this lets you hover over a module name
    # and type 'gf' (for goto file) and open that file in vim. Useful
    # and easier than rope for simple tasks 
    import os.path 
    import sys 
    import vim 
    for p in sys.path:
        if os.path.isdir(p):
            vim.command(r"set path+=%s" % (p.replace(" ", r"\ "))) 
EOF

    endfunction
```

Btw, I don't like to have this load automatically, so I set it to a function that intelligently loads/unloads when I call it/first enter a Python doc.  And I add a `let g:PythonPathLoaded=1` to the previous function.

```
function! GetPythonPath()
    if !exists("g:PythonPathLoaded")
        call LoadPythonPath()
        return
    elseif g:PythonPathLoaded
        return
    else
        call LoadPythonPath()
    endif
endfunction
```

And I have an unload function too...though I'm not sure whether this makes a huge difference.

```
function! UnloadPythonPath()

py <<EOF
    # load PYTHONPATH into vim, this lets you hover over a module name
    # and type 'gf' (for goto file) and open that file in vim. Useful
    # and easier than rope for simple tasks
for p in sys.path:
    if os.path.isdir(p):
        vim.command(r"set path-=%s" % (p.replace(" ", r"\ ")))
EOF

    let g:PythonPathLoaded = 0
endfunction
```

Hope this helps!  Plus, an added bonus is that this will load your packages regardless of whether you are using virtualenv (since it, I believe, runs whatever is set as 'python' at the moment).